# Elasticsearch Query with subquery

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to elasticsearch. I can able to make simple query in dev tools. I need a help on converting the following sql into es query

```
select c.conversationid from conversations c
where c.conversationid not in
 (select s.conversationid from conversations s 
where s.type='end' and s.conversationid=c.conversationid)
```

Index looks like below.

| conversationid | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | start |
| 2 | start |
| 1 | end |
| 3 | start |

If I execute above query I will get the following results.

conversationid

2

3

Comment: Try to use [SQL API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-getting-started.html).

Comment: sql api does not support subquery {
  ```"error": {
    "reason": "There was internal problem at backend",
    "details": "Unsupported subquery",
    "type": "IllegalStateException"
  },
  "status": 503
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following

1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
2. [Bucket Selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

**Query**

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "conversations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "conversationid",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {  --> subaggregation where type == end
        "types": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "type.keyword",
            "include": [
              "end"
            ],
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "select": {   --> select those terms where there is no bucket for "end"
          "bucket_selector": { 
            "buckets_path": {
              "path": "types._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.path==0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "conversations" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "types" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 3,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "types" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```